# MySQL Group By and Sum total value of other column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have 2 columns like this:

| word | amount |
| --- | --- |
| dog | 1 |
| dog | 5 |
| elephant | 2 |

I want to sum the amounts, to get the result

| word | amount |
| --- | --- |
| dog | 6 |
| elephant | 2 |

What I have tried so far (and failed) is this:

```
SELECT word, SUM(amount) FROM `Data` GROUP BY 'word'
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Remove the single quote around the `WORD`. It causes the column name to be converted as string.

```
SELECT word, SUM(amount) 
FROM Data 
Group By word
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple. I feel I should of known that!

Comment: if you want to wrap the column names as well as able name, use `backtick` not single quotes because backticks are for identifiers.

Answer (score 17):

It should be [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) symbol not [single quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe):

```
SELECT word, SUM( amount )
FROM Data
GROUP BY `word`;
```

***Output:***

```
word     SUM(amount)
dog           6
Elephant      2
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT word, SUM(amount) FROM Data Group By word;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this unconventional approach.

```
SELECT word, SUM(amount) 
FROM Data 
Group By word
```

Comment: Repetition of Answers...!!

Comment: Why is this unconventional?  What would be the conventional approach?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column_name1, SUM(column_name2) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY column_name1
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.