# Sum values in one mysql column and group by values of other column (using php foreach)

Tags: php, mysql

Started to write question, but while wrote question, get answer. So not to delete all content, post the answer (possibly may be useful). And also may be there is something to improve.

Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15048890/2465936 answer trying to sum values in one column and group by values in other column

For example, table named `2_1_journal`

```
TransactionPartnerName | Amount
-------------------------------
Name one               |   1
Name two               |   2
Name one               |   3
Name three             |   10
Name two               |   7
Name one               |   150
```

As result want to get this

```
Name one = 154
Name two = 9
Name three = 10
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL query

```
$query_select_all ="
SELECT TransactionPartnerName, SUM(Amount) 
FROM 2_1_journal
GROUP BY TransactionPartnerName";
```

Then

```
$sql = $db->prepare($query_select_all);
$sql->execute();
$sql = $sql->fetchAll();
```

With `print_r($sql);` get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [TransactionPartnerName] => name one [0] => name one [SUM(Amount)] => 154.00 [1] => 154.00 ) [1] => Array ( [TransactionPartnerName] => name three [0] => name three [SUM(Amount)] => 10.00 [1] => 10.00 ) [2] => Array ( [TransactionPartnerName] => name two [0] => name two [SUM(Amount)] => 9.00 [1] => 9.00 ) )
```

So far seems ok.

Then foreach

```
<?php
foreach ($sql as $i1 => $row1) {
?>
<tr>
<td width="90px"><div style="width:90px;">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['TransactionPartnerName'])?>
</div></td>
<td width="50px"><div style="width:53px;">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['SUM(Amount)'])?>
</div></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* `px` is not required in tag attribute; it is used only in CSS, i.e. `<td width="90">` (not recommend) or `<td style="width: 90px;">` (recommend)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting from a database structuring your query to give you this information is almost always better but if that is off the table you can use this.

```
$res = array();
foreach($array as $row){
   // make sure we don't get E_NOTICE's when accessing element for the first time
   if (!isset($res[$row["TransactionPartnerName"]])) $res[$row["TransactionPartnerName"]] =0;
   // Use the array key as a means to group
   $res[$row["TransactionPartnerName"]]+= $row1['SUM(Amount)'];
}

echo "<table>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>Transaction Partner</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($res as $k=>$v){
    echo "<tr><td>".htmlspecialchars($k)."</td><td>".$v</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you create a view of your table.

To Create a View:

1. go to your 2_1_journal table,
2. In the bottom of your table, next to "Display Chart", click "Create View"
   [image]
3. Then You'll See This Display
   [image]
4. In The View name, fill it up to you (e.g: view_2_1_journal)
5. In The AS, fill it with this (OR Like in the picture above):

[image]

6. After That, Your view_2_1_journal successfully created.
7. view_2_1_journal will be like this:

   ```
   TransactionPartnerName | SUM(`Amount`)
   --------------------------------------
   Name one               |   154
   Name two               |   9
   Name three             |   10
   ```
8. To Show it on the php, Use Query Select like you always do, the different is to show the amount, insted of use (for example) something like this: `$show['Amount']`, use this [image], instead.

Hope this help.