# eloquent with Order by not returning correctly the SUM of field

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to work with eloquents and I'm having problems in generating the expected result. 
To be honest, I will show you what I have, what I want and what I did. But, maybe there is another way to do what I want and I will be happy to test it as well. :)

**What I have:**
I do have a table, that is:

```
+----+------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | machine_id | balance_left | balance_found | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 |        12.30 |         12.30 | 2016-01-26 16:39:18 | 2016-01-28 16:39:18 |
|  2 |          2 |        45.60 |         45.60 | 2016-01-26 16:39:18 | 2016-01-28 16:39:18 |
|  3 |          3 |        78.90 |         78.90 | 2016-01-26 16:40:22 | 2016-01-28 16:40:22 |
|  4 |          4 |        90.12 |         90.12 | 2016-01-26 16:40:22 | 2016-01-28 16:40:22 |
|  5 |          1 |         5.60 |          3.40 | 2016-01-28 17:30:33 | 2016-01-28 17:30:33 |
|  6 |          2 |         7.89 |          4.56 | 2016-01-28 17:30:33 | 2016-01-28 17:30:33 |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**What I need:**
Given a date, I do need to get the newest results and SUM the 'balance_left'. *BUT, having the machine_id as unique entry.*
For example, if I pass as date 26/01 at 23:59, I would expect to receive the lines with ID 1, 2, 3 and 4. And, the SUM would be 12.30 + 45.60 + 78.90 + 90.12 = 226.92. 
Now, if I pass as date 28/01 at 23:59,  I would expect to receive the lines with ID 3, 4, 5 and 6. Once that the entries 5 and 6 are the NEWEST entries for the machine_id 1 and 2. In this case, the sum would be: 78.90 +90.12 + 5.60 + 7.89 = 182.51

**What I did:**

```
$sub = App\Transaction::orderBy('created_at','DESC');
$transcations = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))->where('created_at','<=', '2016-01-28 23:59:59')->groupBy('machine_id')->sum('balance_left');
```

Without the SUM, but using a select('balance_left'), I'm getting the correct lines:

```
=> [
     {#672
       +"balance_left": 5.6,
     },
     {#671
       +"balance_left": 7.89,
     },
     {#643
       +"balance_left": 78.9,
     },
     {#677
       +"balance_left": 90.12,
     },
   ]
```

The problem is that when I request the sum, I'm getting:

```
=> 17.9
```

And, after a while, I discovered that actually, he is doing a sum of the machine_id entry, so the lines with ID 1 and 5, have machine_id 1, and then this sum is the sum of 12.30 +5.60 = 17.90

**Problem:**
How can I actually SUM the lines returned? Or, is there any other better way to return what I'm expecting?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See this post, it probably can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048887/mysql-group-by-and-sum-total-value-of-other-column

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but I want almost the opposite of the link that you passed. I don't want the sum of each machine_id, but actually the sum of the all the machine_ids that were returned by the GROUP_BY. I think that is something related to the eloquent that is wrong, but I made different approaches already and didn't get near of what I'm expecting.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. What is the output when you only have the groupBy('machine_id') at the end? check that output and see of calling sum() on it makes sense. You say when you add select('balance_left') you are getting the correct lines, right? So can you all the sum('balance_left') after you select them all?

Comment: So, I was expecting exact what you are saying. that once that I get the correct result using the select (Btw, the group by result also shows the correct lines), I would be able to sum the result of the lines. 
But is not working when I add the sum. clearly the problem is with the way to use eloquent and sum, because the select and group by part is working.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the problem is, but if you get the correct lines using groupBy(), can't you just save the result, then get the sum using something like a loop?

Comment: Yes, I could. 
But I believe that won't be too efficient in comparative with the SUM made direct by mysql, no?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. First of all the sum operation on MySQL end takes time and processor power as well. Plus I am not sure how big your returned result will eventually get, But as long as it is not too big (over 10000 records) it dose not make much of a difference. That being said, if you can get MySQL to handle it, it will be a cleaner code and probably a little bit faster depending on number of your records.