# select sum on column B where column A is the same mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two columns links and open_count:

```
links  open_count
Link1 | 1
Link2 | 6
Link1 | 2
Link3 | 4
Link2 | 6
Link1 | 7
```

I need to select all links where the link are unique and get the sum of all the open_count for that link like :

```
links  open_count
Link1 | 10
Link2 | 12
Link3 | 4
```

Take note: I have tryed "DISTINCT" but it select "link2" only ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql Group By and Sum total value of other column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048887/mysql-group-by-and-sum-total-value-of-other-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
"select links , sum(open_count) as open_count from 'your table' group by links" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select links,sum(open_count)open_count from table_name group by links;
```