# Horizontal group by in SQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT status
     , COUNT(*) total
     , COUNT(s.group_id) totalByGrp
     , s.group_id Groupe
  FROM server s
     , status st
 WHERE s.id = st.server_id
   AND st.created = (SELECT MAX(ss.created) 
                       FROM status ss
                      WHERE ss.server_id = s.id)
 GROUP 
    BY st.status
     , s.group_id
```

this query return this table

```
 status     total   totalByGrp  Groupe  
canc          3           3       10
canc          2           2       11
inst          1           1       10
inst          2           2       11
new           2           2       10
prod          1           1       10
prod          2           2       11
```

i want group by GROUP(Horizontal nit vertical like table above) return the table like :

```
status      total   Grp_10  Grp_11  
canc          5           3       2
inst          3           1       2
new           2           2       0
prod          3           1       2
ret           4           2       2
toRet         2           2       0
```

Comment: maybe this wil help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048887/mysql-group-by-and-sum-total-value-of-other-column . Just to be clear. You want to group Status and count the total right

Comment: What are `Grp_10` and `Grp_11`?

Comment: It's possible that changing `group by st.status,s.group_id` to `group by st.status` will solve most of your problems, but it's very unclear how the second and third column should work.

Comment: Typically, issues of data display are best handled in a presentation layer (e.g. a simple php loop)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this in Mysql query. you will have to use case statement and manually convert the rows in to columns. Still you will have to know all possible combinations

```
select sum(case when Groupe = 10 then Groupe else 0 end ) as Grp_10,
...
...
from ...
```

Otherwise you may export the results to a CSV and do the necessary pivoting in spreadsheet software like excel