# MySql Group By and Sum total value of column, displayed with min value

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have two questions:

1. How to group and sum a column.
2. How to displayed the result with a min sum value

I got my 1st answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048887/mysql-group-by-and-sum-total-value-of-other-column)
on how to group and sum the column, but I need to filter out by min amount of 100 ..

I tried

```
SELECT 
    member_code, SUM(product_price) as totalSales
FROM 
    src_calculation_daily
WHERE 
    totalSales > 100
GROUP BY 
    member_code
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  What does "min sum value" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT member_code, sum(product_price) as totalSales
FROM src_calculation_daily
GROUP BY member_code
HAVING totalSales > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for HAVING

`SELECT member_code, sum(product_price) as totalSales FROM src_calculation_daily GROUP BY member_code HAVING totalSales > 100`

WHERE is used when the fields exists in your table

HAVING is used on a calculated value