# count sum of a column and group it by column with same value

Tags: mysql, sql

how to select the sum of the number column and then group it with name

```
name | number
a    | 100
b    | 10
a    | 50
b    | 40
c    | 200
a    | 20

expected result :

name | number
a    | 170
b    | 50
c    | 200
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048887/mysql-group-by-and-sum-total-value-of-other-column

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it i am sorry

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(NUMBER) AS NUMBER FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, 
SUM (number)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name;
```